# Add item to array on ReactJs state with timeout for self removal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a created a MessageList component for displaying return messages from the server, I want these messages to only exist in the state for around 5 seconds or so, I have it all working as I want for adding and displaying, but I cant think for the life of me how to timeout the removal of a specific item from its parent array.. a Vanilla JS answer will do for timeout removal of self from array.

```
var MainApp = React.createClass({
     AddComment: function() {
        //do some stuff 
        this.showMessage({
            alerttype: "success", 
            title: "Success!", 
            message: "Comment saved to the database."})
        }
    },
    showMessage: function(message) {
        //how to I push this message onto messages for 5 seconds?
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {messages: []};
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="mainApp">
                <CommentForm messages={this.state.messages} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is wrap the removal in a setTimeout.  Something like the below:

```
showMessage: function(message) {
    this.setState({
        messages: this.state.messages.concat([message])
    });

    setTimeout(() => this.setState({
        messages: this.state.messages.filter(m => m !== message)
    }), 5000);
},
```

Comment: Hmm, that's exactly what I have been trying to do without success - my message is not just a string though it's a slightly more complex object

Comment: It shouldn't matter what type message is

Comment: @NickDewitt Can you include the code you tried in your question?

Comment: I am just doing it now, I have it working now - I am generating an id per message generated and using that as a key to remove itself

Comment: @NickDewitt An id shouldn't be necessary.  You should be able to check on reference equality.

Comment: I would just like to say, what a perfect answer, exactly what I asked for and what I had already convinced myself wasn't possible based on some other answer about finding items in arrays with IndexOf etc. (sorry I can only vote it up once!)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to abstract this from your view logic. We can make a data type that's responsible for storing timestamped messages. We can also add some helper functions to remove old items and to retrieve the current list of items. Then all you need to do is occasionally purge any old items:

```
function ExpiringMessages(expirationTime) {
    this.messages = [];
}

ExpiringMessages.prototype.add = function (data) {
    this.messages.push({ timestamp: Date.now(), data });
}

ExpiringMessages.prototype.removeOlderThan = function (delta) {
    this.messages = this.messages.filter(m => (Date.now() -  m.time) - delta > 0);
}

ExpiringMessages.prototype.current = function () {
    return this.messages.map(m => m.data);
}
```

This basically just stores a list of timestamped data that allows you to purge any items whenever you want. Within your component, you would set an interval (maybe every second or so) that would remove items that are older than 5 seconds. Each time you do this, you would reset the current list of messages to be `messages.current()`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is use timestamps on messages and add a separate cleanup method on a 5 second timeout:

- inside `showMessage()`, update your state with the new message, and add a timestamp to the new message.
- add a `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle method, which calls a `cleanMessages()` method, and fires a 5 second timeout to call the `cleanMessages()` method` again.
- inside the `cleanMessages()` method, check if any of the messages in the list is > 5 seconds old (by comparing current time to timestamp in each message), remove found old messages, and ***only if there are messages removed***, do a `setState()` with the updated messages list.

By the way, it looks like the line `}.bind(this);` in your code breaks the code and should be removed.

Comment: Hi @wintvelt, nope the `}.bind(this)` passes the this object from the react component to the function, `this.showMessage` doesn't work without it..

Comment: @NickDewitt count your brackets. If I am not mistaken, you should remove at least the leading } from the bind line.  To bind this to the showMessage call, instead of the addComment object..

Comment: Right you are sir, I incorrectly stripped some irrelevant stuff out from my actual version